# Is it possible to pass a cython function as argument to a scipy function?

Tags: scipy, cython

Scipy has many functions that accept a python callable to perform some operation. In particular, I'm working with a mathematical optimization function `scipy.optimize.leastsq` that accepts a Python callable as objective function argument. This objective function can be called by `leastsq` lots of times during the minimization process.

My profiling shows that a lot of time is spent on that objective function. I have sped up some parts of the function using Cython. However, the function itself is still a Python function and calling it repeatedly (as `leastsq` does)  has some overhead.

I think I could get a further increase in speed if the function was a Cython function  (using `cdef` instead of `def`). So I put my call to `leastsq` inside the Cython extension and pass a Cython objective function to it. But when I do this **I get a compile error at the**  `leastsq` **call:**

```
Cannot convert 'object (object, object, object)' to Python object
```

**Is there any way to pass a Cython function as an argument to these Scipy functions that require python callables?**

Or, in my case, **is there any way to access the underlying** `leastsq` **implementation and pass the Cython objective function to it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing `cdef` functions in is not possible currently. Passing callback functions to the underlying Fortran code is also not possible, as it's wrapped with f2py which doesn't know about Cython.

What you can do is:

- Write your function as Cython's `def` function. These can be passed in to all Scipy's routines. This does not remove the additional function call overhead which comes from using Python's callback mechanism (which might not be significant!), but you **can** speed up the implementation of your function, and this might well be enough. Just remember to `cdef` the variables appearing in, as usual when writing Cython code.
- Copy the MINPACK source codes from Scipy or netlib.org, and use them directly yourself. This gets rid of the remaining function call overhead by replacing Python function callback mechanism by the low-level one.

(There have been discussions on adding a protocol for passing low-level function pointers around exactly for this purpose, which could be adopted by any Python-based system having a need for it, but AFAIK the design is not completed, and not implemented in Cython & Scipy.)

Comment: Thanks. I have done the first suggestion, to keep my objective function as a python function and speed up its code in cython. I got some speed up but not too much as the original code was already mostly vectorized with numpy. 
About the second suggestion, I have been digging for a while trying to call lmdif in the _minpack.pyd and pass my objective function with the signature `cdef int raw_multipack_lm_function(int *m, int *n, double *x, double *fvec, int *iflag)`  but I'm having lots of errors and I'm stuck, I wonder if you could refer me to some example how to do that.

Comment: I don't have an example at hand. However, I'd suggest that you recheck that the time is actually not still spent inside the function eg. just via time.time(). I'd expect the performance improvement of using the second option to be not very important, unless your function is rather fast to evaluate.

Comment: Ok. I've measured how long is spent inside the objective function with respect to how long it takes the leastsq optimization. I spend about 69% of the time in the objective function for a test that resulted in 41 objective function evaluations. I imagine that the time spent in call overhead must be a small part of the remaining 31%. I'll leave it as it is, with the python call, and focus on speed up the objective function.  thanks for your help.