# Cythonized function unexpectedly slow

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I wanted to speed up a function that I'm using a lot and I though about using cython. However, after trying all the possible cython optimizations that I've been able to find in the documentation, the cython code is about 6 times slower than the python+numpy function. Disappointing!

This is my test code: (forward1 is the python function, forward2 is the cython function)

```
#geometry.py
def forward1(points, rotation, translation):
    '''points are in columns'''
    return np.dot(rotation, points - translation[:, np.newaxis])

#geometry.pyx
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef np.float64_t[:,:] forward2(np.float64_t[:,:] points, np.float64_t[:,:] rotation, np.float64_t[:] translation):
    '''points are in columns'''
    cdef unsigned int I, J
    I = points.shape[0]
    J = points.shape[1]
    cdef np.float64_t[:,:] tmp = np.empty((I, J), dtype=np.float64)
    cdef unsigned int i
    for i in range(J):
        tmp[0, i] = points[0, i] - translation[0]        
        tmp[1, i] = points[1, i] - translation[1]        
    cdef np.float64_t[:,:] result = np.dot(rotation, tmp)
    return result

def test_forward2(points, rotation, translation):
    import timeit
    cdef np.float64_t[:,:] points2 = points
    cdef np.float64_t[:,:] rotation2 = rotation
    cdef np.float64_t[:] translation2 = translation
    t = timeit.Timer(lambda: forward2(points2, rotation2, translation2))
    print min(t.repeat(3, 10))
```

and then I time it:

```
t = timeit.Timer(lambda: forward1(points, rotation, translation))
print min(t.repeat(3, 10))
0.000368164520751

test_forward2(points, rotation, translation)
0.0023365181969
```

Is there anything I can do to the cython code to make it faster?

If forward1 can't be sped up in cython, can I hope any speed up using weave?

**EDIT:**

Just for the record, another thing I've tried to speed up the function is to pass points in fortran order, as my points are stored in columns and there are quite a few of them. I also define the local tmp as fortran order. I think the subtraction part of the function should be faster but numpy.dot seems to require a C order output (anyway to work around this?), so altogether there is no speed up with this either. I also tried to transpose the points so that the subtraction part is faster in C order, but it seems the dot product is still the most expensive part.

Also, I noticed that numpy.dot can't use memoryviews as out argument, even if it's C order, is this a bug?

Comment: `numpy` is already using `c` and `fortran` libraries for calculations. usually you don't need to do anything to get speedups..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just glancing at your code, it looks like something (A subtraction of arrays and dot product.) that `numpy` is already very optimized for.

Cython is great for speeding up cases where numpy often performs poorly (e.g. iterative algorithms where the iteration is written in python), but in this case, the inner loop is already being preformed by a BLAS library.

If you want to speed things up, the first place I'd look is what BLAS/LAPACK/ATLAS/etc libraries numpy is linked against.  Using a "tuned" linear algebra library (e.g. ATLAS or Intel's MKL) will make a large (>10x in some cases) difference in cases like this.

To find out what you're currently using have a look at the output of `numpy.show_config()`

Comment: OK thanks, I understand. I have run numpy.show_config() but I'm not sure how interpret the results:  <br/>
`mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95', 'mkl_blas95', 'mkl_intel_c', ...]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Compiler/11.1/070/mkl/ia32/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Compiler/11.1/070/mkl/include']`
I get similar structure for lapack_opt_info, blas_opt_info, lapack_mkl_info and blas_mkl_info
does this mean my numpy version was linked against MKL? or the [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)] means it didn't?

Comment: Just for the record, my numpy version is '1.6.2' and I installed it with EPD free distribution on a windows7 box

Comment: Yep, your numpy is linked agains MKL.  My suggestion isn't going to help you much, then. The MKL is about as optimized as you can get.

Comment: Another thought: Are you typically calling this a lot of times for small input arrays? There's a lot of overhead in a call to any particular numpy function.  If you're iterating through a larger array and calling this function many times you may be able to get a speedup by using `tensordot` or `einsum` and operating on all of the larger array at once.  Of course, if you're not iterating through a larger array, this won't help any.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm calling this function with hundreds of points and this is part of the objective function in a minimization process. Actually, it is the minimization I talk about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847632/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-cython-function-as-argument-to-a-scipy-function)  I think I can't put all the points together as the minimization is sequential.

Comment: Yeah, for a minimization problem you certainly need sequential calls.  In that case, it's best to try to reduce the number of times the objective function is called. You might consider using an optimization algorithm that doesn't need to calculate the gradient at each step (e.g. Powell's method), as this will (usually) reduce the number of times the objective function is called. Also, if it's at all possible to make a better starting guess, this can dramatically reduce the number of iterations minimization takes. You might consider loosening the tolerances of the minimization, as well.